# Vertica, distinct Case Statement

Tags: sql, vertica

I have the following

```
CASE WHEN S.name = 'Stack'   THEN E.Price 
     WHEN M.Type = 'Pricing' THEN V.value * V.Rate 
END AS "Price"
```

However I am getting duplicate records even though I start my full sql statement with a `select distinct`

It seems like the distinct for my sql statement isnt giving a distinct for above part? I dont want to exclude `<null>` from the price column either.

sample data:

```
+----------+------------------------+---------
| Currency |      Type              | Price  |
+----------+------------------------+---------
| USD      | stack                  | <null> |
| USD      | stack                  | 236.34 |
+----------+------------------------+---------
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I agree - provide sample data and results. But a general note - distinct doesn't do what you think if you're selecting non-distinct data. You'll probably need a sub query from which you select distinct.

Comment: it is hard to understand your question without any sample data / result. Just imagine you are trying to answer a similar question by another user, and you will understand how difficult it is to answer a question out of void (i.e. no evidence, non repeatable)

Comment: Updated. I can't jsut get rid of `<null>` . Because I have other data where `<null>` is expected. I only need to get rid of it where `Type` is the same.